# React not loading properly image files on Windows

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, jsx

I am trying to import image files to component by using:

> import Icon from './cpp.png';

File can be found but it is not visible in browser on Windows 10. While cloning this project and opening same project on linux everything is displayed properly.

Sadly using url-loader or file-loader and configuring regex to find files in Public folder doesn't solve issue, result is same as before in file not loading properly (but can be found) as image below shows. [image]

I am using same version of react on Windows and Linux (linux uses slightly older npm)

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
```

I also tried with specifying path to string and requre like this:

> let java = require('./Icons/java.svg');

file can be found but it is not displayed properly (like image below shows)

Template react with import works but it doesn't work in this specific project.

Comment: So what is your image links in DOM ? I mean rendered image elements sources

Comment: I'm not really sure if I know what you mean by images links in DOM. I'm using it like this: `<MyCard name={'c++'} path={java} text={'Konstrukcja programów desktopowych'}/>` java is imported icon like this: `import Java from './java.png` And files are png and svg. It works on linux machine but not on windows one.